# Send dict data from one file to another in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, websocket

I took a Django project from someone.

I just want to make a change in this but because of my lack of understanding of how Django works, I am not able to do it correctly.

Let me explain the structure.

In the apps dir, there is a Home dir.

Within the home, there is this file called views.py.

In views.py, another file is being imported from the same dir like this:
`from apps.home.temp import tempClassName`

Inside login function, an object is made and the methods inside temp.py are executed.
In one such line of temp.py, a variable is created by making an API call.

Insted of using API Call, I want it to use websocket code to get data for that variable.

consider temp.py:

```
class tempClassName:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def tempMethod(self):
        # some code
        x = apiCall()
        # Some other code
```

consider view.py:

```
from apps.home.temp import tempClassName

def login(request):

    tempObj = tempClassName()
    tempObj.tempMethod()
```

consider websocket.py:

```
import something

# set some connections
ws = getWebsocket()

dict = {1:-1, 2:-1}


def on_event(ws, data):
    dict[data[0]['key']] = data[0]['desired_data']
    print(dict)

def on_connect(ws, response):
    ws.subscribe([1,2])

ws.on_event = on_event
ws.on_connect = on_connect

ws.connect()
```

I have successfully run and tested the websocket.py file and I get the data.

I want to integrate my websocket code with Django code such that in temp.py, it doesn't make an API call but takes value from this file.

At any time, I access the `dict` variable inside `temp.py`, it should give me the data received in last second.

Note I can't merge the code of websocket.py and temp.py in the same file.
temp.py is just one file, there are other files as well which would need the data from the dict.
I am thinking is there a way to start the websocket.py file from view.py and somehow get the data dict inside temp.py (and subsequently in other files as well).

Comment: Have you tried importing websocket.py into temp.py? Doing that should give you access to dict. Also I don't know if you just named it that for stack overflow, but if your variable's named dict in your codebase, I would recommend renaming it to something else as 'dict' is a keyword in Python